# Fake/Paket "specified module could not be found" in build file

Tags: dll, f#, .net-assembly, f#-fake, paket

I created the following Github repo to document the problem:
https://github.com/red-swan/fake-sqlite-problem

I am unable to build `sqlite` databases from an F# `FAKE` file relying on `Paket`. Adding the nuget package `System.Data.SQLite` to the `paket.dependencies` means I can `open System.Data.SQLite` but when attempting to build a database from the `build.fsx` file, I get the following error:

`(Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E))`

`SQLite.Interop.dll` is a located in dependency `runtimes\win-x64\native\netstandard2.0` of `System.Data.SQLite`'s dependency `System.Data.SQLite.Core`. Trying to reference it directly with and `#r` statement in the `build.fsx` fails with the error:

`Error opening binary file ... bad cli header, rva`

I'm not sure how everything is supposed to resolve, but running the database creation from an actual `fsproj` works just fine, so I believe it has do with the `FAKE` or `Paket` resolution.

If you are familiar with `FAKE`, does this sound reasonable? Do you know how to fix this?

To reproduce the error:
`git clone https://github.com/red-swan/fake-sqlite-problem.git`

Comment: I don't think it has to do with FAKE or Paket as such, but rather with DLL discovery in FSI, which is used to run the script. Have a look at http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/loading-native-dlls-in-fsharp-interactive.html

Comment: That did it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above comment by `TeaDrivenDev` has the solution. I'm putting the answer here so I can close the question.

To be specific, I found the Native dll `SQLite.Interop.dll` and dropped it into the root folder where the FAKE `build.fsx` file is. The article `TeaDrivenDev` references has alternative methods as well.